# How to fix moon+ reader voice stuttering in Android 9?

Tags: moon-reader

With my Samsung s8+ and android 8 I could listen to ebooks with the voice reader without problems but since upgrading to Android 9 it stutters and produces strange noise and stops. How can I fix that?

I use Moon+ Reader Pro 4.5.7.

P.S.: The problem only occurs with the Google Voice, not the Samsung Voice.

Comment: Have you considered asking the dev? Seany is quite responsive (at least he was in the past). Maybe it's something he can fix.

Comment: Thanks, I will contact him!

Comment: Let us know the outcome then! And give him my regards :)